# Getting Rails Nested Resources to Route to correct nested Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing, controllers, nested-resources

In Rails 3.2.11, I have the following route definitions

```
resources :foos do
    resources :bars
    resources :bangs, :controller => 'foos/bangs'
end
```

which result in the following routes

```
     foo_bars GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars(.:format)            bars#index
              POST   /foos/:foo_id/bars(.:format)            bars#create
  new_foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/new(.:format)        bars#new
 edit_foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id/edit(.:format)   bars#edit
      foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id(.:format)        bars#show
              PUT    /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id(.:format)        bars#update
              DELETE /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id(.:format)        bars#destroy
    foo_bangs GET    /foos/:foo_id/bangs(.:format)           foos/bangs#index
              POST   /foos/:foo_id/bangs(.:format)           foos/bangs#create
 new_foo_bang GET    /foos/:foo_id/bangs/new(.:format)       foos/bangs#new
edit_foo_bang GET    /foos/:foo_id/bangs/:id/edit(.:format)  foos/bangs#edit
     foo_bang GET    /foos/:foo_id/bangs/:id(.:format)       foos/bangs#show
              PUT    /foos/:foo_id/bangs/:id(.:format)       foos/bangs#update
              DELETE /foos/:foo_id/bangs/:id(.:format)       foos/bangs#destroy
         foos GET    /foos(.:format)                         foos#index
              POST   /foos(.:format)                         foos#create
      new_foo GET    /foos/new(.:format)                     foos#new
     edit_foo GET    /foos/:id/edit(.:format)                foos#edit
          foo GET    /foos/:id(.:format)                     foos#show
              PUT    /foos/:id(.:format)                     foos#update
              DELETE /foos/:id(.:format)                     foos#destroy
```

The paths are all correct, but the controller routing is only correct for `resources :bangs`. The `resources :bars` should route to the `foos/bars` controller rather than the `bars` controller.

It used to be that I could set up namespaced controllers within `foos/` to handle the nested resource.

```
#app/controllers/foos/bars_controller.rb

class Foos::BarsController < ApplicationController
    #/foos/:foo_id/bar/:id available here
end
```

However this doesn't seem to be the case any more. When did this behavior change and how do I get the same functionality in Rails 3.2.11?

**EDIT**: I realize the `resources :bangs` results in the correct controller mapping, but I'd like to be able to have that done implicitly. If I have several nested resources within `:foos`, I don't want to have to define the controller for every resource.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add a scope to specify the module.  Rails assumes that the controllers for your nested resources are not themselves nested.

```rb
resources :foos do
    scope module: :foos do
        resources :bars
        resources :bangs
    end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the way to do it. I forgot I had this question still on here.

Comment: I figured someone else might still find your question relevant.

Comment: @PhillSparks, could you take a look at this issue? It's almost the same, but I can't figure it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672666/rails-structuring-routes-controller-views-for-nested-resources

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :foos do
  resources :bars, :controller -> 'foos/bars'
  resources :bangs, :controller => 'foos/bangs'
end
```

Isn't this what you require?

Comment: Yes and no. I'd like to **NOT** have to specify the controller for each resource. In a rails 2.3 app, nesting the resources was enough to map the correct path and controllers.