# rails structuring routes/controller/views for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller, routes

I have rails app with the following structure:

`user has_many posts`
`post has_many post_comments`
`post_comment has_many comment_replies`

I'm planning to use the following routes to avoid deep nesting.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :post_comments, module: :posts
end

resources :comments do 
  resources :comment_replies, module: :post_comments #is this module a good choice?
end
```

This gives the following controller structure

```
post_comments      GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  posts/comments#index
                   POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                       posts/comments#create
new_post_comment   GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)                   posts/comments#new
 edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)              posts/comments#edit
      post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#show
                   PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#update
                   PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#update
                   DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#destroy


comment_repiles     GET    /comments/:comment_id/repiles(.:format)                  comments/repiles#index
                    POST   /comments/:comment_id/repiles(.:format)                  comments/repiles#create
 new_comment_repile GET    /comments/:comment_id/repiles/new(.:format)              comments/repiles#new
edit_comment_repile GET    /comments/:comment_id/repiles/:id/edit(.:format)         comments/repiles#edit
     comment_repile GET    /comments/:comment_id/repiles/:id(.:format)              comments/repiles#show
                    PATCH  /comments/:comment_id/repiles/:id(.:format)              comments/repiles#update
                    PUT    /comments/:comment_id/repiles/:id(.:format)              comments/repiles#update
                    DELETE /comments/:comment_id/repiles/:id(.:format)              comments/repiles#destroy
```

My problem is with sturcturing the folders.

For controllers: It means I put the `posts_controller` in the main folder and the `post_comments_controller` goes into `posts` folder. Until now it's clear. But for `comment_replies` I should put it in the `comment_replies` folder which is totally separated from where `post_comments_controller` can be found.

For views: I have a `create.js.erb` for `posts` in the 'post' folder. I have a `create.js.erb` for `post_comment` in the `posts/post_comments` folder. According to my routes I should put the `create.js.erb` for `comment_replies` into the `post_comments/comment_replies folder`. But this seems to be counterintuitive again just like the controller example.

What is the rails convention/ common solution in this case? Btw. I don't wanna show comments or replies separately from their post.

UPDATE

posts_controller

```
def index
  ....
  @post_comments = @post.post_comments #showing all comments
  @post_comment = PostComment.new #new comment via js
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

post_comments controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(post_comment_params)
  @post_comment.save!
end
```

Comment: Personally, I don't see why you want to namespace your controller. And your namespacing seems tortured. Are you **sure** you want to namespace your controllers? There can be good reasons to do it, but I don't see from your example that this is one of them.

Comment: I'd like to keep folders structured. Comments and replies will be only showed/used on the post index or post show site.

Comment: PostComments and CommentReplies will only be shown/used via the PostController (thus only on post.index and post.show)? The you only need a PostController. You don't need a controller for PostComment and CommentReply.

Comment: jvillian, update my answer with current solution. As I see I'd use post_comments and comment_replies controller for create/update/destroy actions like in my example in the question. How would you solve this whole problem? Can you answer with some code example pls (controllers + routes + controller/view folder structure)? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No, I can't answer with some code examples. You have a multi-faceted problem here. Our job is not to write your code or even do your high-level design. Keep working on it. And when you have specific questions - maybe we can help.

Comment: Easiest way to learn is being able to see how others made the given thing happen. When you say you only need a PostsController that doesn't help at all. It's like you are saying you make shitty things but I don't tell you what to do. I keep working on it and I can implement  this stuff, I just wanna make sure that I do it the right way.